# Python Socket HTTP 1.1 keep-alive for a HEAD request

Tags: python, sockets, http

For the HTTP 1.1 protocol, the connections are persistent (keep-alive). 
The client should send `Connection:close` header attribute to close the connection. 
In a Python program, this is the case for a GET request. However, a connection for a HEAD request is closed without the `Connection:close` header.

What is the issue?

I have also tested a Java version of a HEAD request, and the connection is persistent there.

Python program for a HEAD request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    s.connect(("webcode.me" , 80))
    s.sendall(b"HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: webcode.me\r\nAccept: text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print(str(s.recv(1024), 'utf-8'))
```

Python program for a GET request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    s.connect(("webcode.me" , 80))
    s.sendall(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: webcode.me\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
    # s.sendall(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: webcode.me\r\nAccept: text/html\r\n\r\n")

    while True:

        data = s.recv(512)

        if not data:
            break

        print(data.decode())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the HTTP 1.1 protocol, the connections are persistent (keep-alive)

No, the connections **can** be persistent if the server also wants them to be persistent. The server might decide to close the connection immediately, 5 seconds after ... or even never by its own if the client signals support for persistence.

> However, a connection for a HEAD request is closed without the Connection:close header.

It is your client which is closing the connection, not the server. Your client does a single `recv` and then it is done with the socket and the program. If one would modify the code to continue with `recv` until no more data can be read then (similar to your second program) then the client would hang since the server is waiting for the new request from the client.

Comment: Is the `if not data: break` redundant then? I though that at the end an empty string might be sent indicating end of communication, which would terminate the loop.

Comment: @JanBodnar: "Empty strings" cannot be sent via TCP since TCP is a byte stream, i.e. either there is at least a byte (some data, i.e. not an empty string) or there is none (no data, i.e. nothing to send). To find out where a HTTP message ends you need instead to parse the HTTP protocol as defined in the standard, i.e.   read first the HTTP header and determine from its content where the HTTP body will end. This is far from trivial and much more than a simple `recv`.